# pkg_check_modules doesn't resolve, because dependency doesn't have .pc file

Tags: cmake

There's a library, let's say **libA**. **libA** has its pkg-config file **libA.pc**. **libA** has a dependency, **libB**. **libB** is present in the build system (headers + compiled shared object), but doesn't have its own **.pc** file. Therefore `pkg_check_modules` is failing when trying to resolve **libA**. What is the proper way to solve this situation, should be added the ***.pc** file for **libB**?

Comment: `pkg_check_modules` performs **single** call to `pkg-config` utility about the requested package. So i am not sure what do you mean by "`libA` has a dependency, `libB`". This couldn't be a CMake-level dependency, as it cannot be requested when us `pkg_check_modules`. Is it `pkg-config`-level dependency, expressed by `libA.pc` file? If so, then you need to provide everything what is needed for `pkg-config` to work. CMake is unrelated in this respect.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I meant that libA.pc states on the line beginning with "Requires.private" that it requires libB.

Comment: So you have no other way than provide `libB.pc` for make `pkg-config` happy. As I said, CMake is mostly unrelated in this respect.